# Tool to create a Windows Event from a JSON message received on a TCP port

Tags: windows, email

I have here a 3rd-party Windows Applikation that can send alert events as JSON or CSV streams to any TCP port.
I am looking for a simple way to turn these TCP messages into Windows Events.
The final goal is to create an email message for each alert event content. Perhaps it's not needed to use Windows Eventlog.

Is there any existing, simple Windows application which listens on a configurable TCP port and would allow me to either create a Windows Eventlog entry from a TCP mesage, or directly send an email message?

I am not much of a programmer, so a little tool would be great. On the other hand, I could imagine that a Powershell script might be able to do what I want.

Any pointer is very welcome.
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do this using [ncat](https://nmap.org/ncat/guide/index.html).   Despite the unixy flavor of the docs it's also supported on Windows.  It will take some work on your side, but no programming is required.

1. [How to listen to a port](https://nmap.org/ncat/guide/ncat-usage.html#ncat-listen)
2. [How to send email with ncat](https://nmap.org/ncat/guide/ncat-tricks.html#ncat-smtp)
3. [How to connect 2 ncats together](https://nmap.org/ncat/guide/ncat-tricks.html#ncat-chain)